# how to configure rollup-plugin-inline-svg in the svelte-kit?

Tags: svelte, rollup, sveltekit, inline-svg

I am trying to add [rollup-plugin-inline-svg](https://github.com/sionzee/rollup-plugin-inline-svg)

For `inline svg` but it broking all the svg?
Has anyone know how to configure this for inline-svg.

Comment: Please explain what happened in detail. "it broke" isn't actionable.

Comment: @Phix `GET http://localhost:3000/wiki/export%20default%20%22/public/assets/svg/arrow-right.svg%22 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: `export%20default%20%22` was added by plugin

Comment: Also please show your code.